# Renderizar array corretamente em rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicacao em rails, porem esbarrei em um problema que pode ser simples, mas ta me matando por dentro. Tenho um indicador em uma tela que mostra a quantidade de creditos que o coach selecionado possui, e a quantidade de coachees associados ao coach selecionado. No controller de coachs, na parte edit, eu busco essas informacoes no banco de dados da seguinte maneira:

Para buscar a quantidade de coachees associados:

```
@total_coachees = @current_account.coachees
  .where(coach_id: params[:id])
@act_coaches = (@total_coachees.activated.select(:id).count)
```

Obtendo o resultado correto, e imprimindo na view com um simples `@act_coachees`, onde a view apresenta apenas o numero desejado, **3**

Para obter a quantidade de creditos:

```
@total_cents = @current_account.coaches
  .where(id: params[:id])
@total = (@total_cents.select(:credits_available).to_a)
```

Imprimindo na view como o anterior, utilizando `@total`
Porem, os resultados sao inconsistentes, utilizando **.to_a** no final da query, o rails imprime na view o seguinte resultado:

```
[#<Coach id: nil, credits_available: 200>]
```

Alterando para **to_json**, obtenho:

```
[{"id":null,"credits_available":200}]
```

E nao colocando nenhum formato no final, obtenho:

```
#<Coach::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00007f7a341dbe50>
```

Esses resultados impressos na tela, da maneira que estao apresentados aqui.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alterando a pesquisa de:

```
@total = (@total_cents.select(:credits_available).to_a)
```

para:

```
@total = (@total_cents.pluck(:credits_available))
```

Consigo buscar apenas a coluna *credits_available* no banco, retornando um array com um objeto, para renderizar, utilizei

```
@total.first
```

O*.first* sendo usado para selecionar o primeiro objeto do array, mesmo tempo apenas um, ou ele imprime o array com [] na view.